# Java Wrapper Class not found

Tags: java, java-service-wrapper

I am trying to install a wrapper for a JBoss 4 App.

My `wrapper.conf` contains:

```
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
```

Yet I get the error below:

```
INFO   | wrapper  | 2014/09/05 17:10:36 | Waiting to start...

STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/09/05 17:10:40 | Launching a JVM...

INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/09/05 17:10:40 | ***java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/tanukisoftware/wrapper/WrapperSimpleApp***

INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/09/05 17:10:40 | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp

INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/09/05 17:10:40 |   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)

INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/09/05 17:10:40 |   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/09/05 17:10:40 |   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)

INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/09/05 17:10:40 |   at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)

INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/09/05 17:10:40 |   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)

INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/09/05 17:10:40 |   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/09/05 17:10:40 | Could not find the main class: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.  Program will exit.

INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/09/05 17:10:40 | Exception in thread "main" 

ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/09/05 17:10:40 | JVM exited while loading the application.
```

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: please understand there is a difference between class not found and class def not found

Comment: how does your WrapperSimpleApp class look?

Answer (score 0):

Class not found error is because the class may not be found in the build path of the project but class def not found would be cause of the manifest not having the imports.

Suggestion:

Delete manifest file and regenerate the project e.g.: mvn clean install